# Why did Kreacher not appear after Sirius shouted for him?

Tags: harry-potter

In the 'Order of the Phoenix' Sirius shouted for Kreacher (after sending him away unintentionally) and he did not reappear. But when Harry shouted for him (so he could spy on Malfoy) in 'The Half-Blood Prince' Kreacher apparated at once. Why did he not appear for Sirius although he was his master back then?